# Anaconda Prompt で unix　コマンドを使いたい

Tags: python, linux, windows, fortran

50代エンジニアの疑問です。
若い方には馴染まないかもしれません。

Anacondaでmingw(gcc, gfortran) をインストールすることは下記のように可能なようです。
conda install -c anaconda mingw

できれば、unixコマンド(bash, vim, sed, awk, find, ...)を使いたいのですが、condaのリストの中にあるのでしょうか？
conda list で表示したのですが、さっぱりわかりません。

ご存じの方が居たら、お願いします。

MinGWを便利に使っていたのですが、最近話題のPython(numpy, scipy, matplotlib)を導入したいです。
MinGWも最近メンテナンスされていないようです。

unixコマンド（特に、シェル環境）は何に置き換わっているのでしょうか？
powershell, batファイル？

Comment: `linux`タグが付いてますが、Windows環境で Unixコマンドと anaconda を使いたいというご質問でしょうか？

Comment: タグがわかりにくくて申し訳ありません。そのとおりです。MinGWの環境でPython(numpy, scipy, matplotlib)を使いたかったのですが、scipy, のインストールでエラーが出て旨く行きません。逆にAnacondaの環境で、Mingwはインストール可能で、Gccやgfortranは使えますが、unixコマンドが使えません。GUIでなくて良いので、両立したいです。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 関連: ["I want to use unix command in anaconda prompt"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44736212/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

MinGWの代わりに[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)を使えば Windows上でUNIX Shell環境 が使えます。gcc なども cygwin に含まれており、インストーラで パッケージを選択すればインストールされます。(fortranはよくわかりませんが たぶんあるんじゃないかと…)

次に Anaconda (Windows版) を Cygwin から動かすことができます。
Anaconda のインストール先 を Cygwin 側の 環境変数 PATH に加えれば 普通に使えると思います。

ただ、いくつかハマリやすい点がありますので ご注意ください。

1. Cygwin から Windows の ドライブは `/cygdrive/ドライブレター/` というパスで見えますので 適宜読み替えて、環境変数PATH を適切に設定してください。
   例）インストール先が `C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3` の場合、Cygwin からは `/cygdrive/C/Users/ユーザ名/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3` となる。
2. Cygwin用のTerminalアプリケーションで mintty.exe というのがあり、Windowsの例の黒い画面よりいい感じではあるのですが、コレを使うと windows版 python は正常に動きません。Shellの起動は バッチファイル (`CYGWINインストール先\Cygwin.bat`) を実行してください。そうしますと 例の黒い画面で Shellが起動します。 [Improve support for native console programs · Issue #56 · mintty/mintty](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56) によると `xterm` `rxvt` などでも 同様の症状になるそうです。

```
$ ANACONDA_HOME=/cygdrive/C/Users/take88/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3
$ PATH=$ANACONDA_HOME:$ANACONDA_HOME/Scripts:$PATH
$ export PATH
$ which python
/cygdrive/C/Users/take88/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python
$ which conda
/cygdrive/C/Users/take88/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。昨日Windows用の情報（BOW）Bashを見つけました。 Windows 10にBOWとAnacondaをインストールしました。 これで試してみます。 Cygwin→MinGWとWindows上でunixを使ってきましたが、マイクロソフトのBOWによって安定した環境を得ることができそうです。BOWは役に立ちそうで、楽しみです。